# SSRS passing parameters to a second tablix in the same report making it visible

Tags: ssrs-2012

I need to pass parameters to a second tablix in the same report from clicking in a cell on the first tablix a bit like adding an action to a text box that passes parameters to a second report. The second tablix needs to be hidden until the row in the details column on the first tablix is clicked.
I'm not sure if this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Have just tried SQL Dan's method and that also has worked for me. Pointing the Action of a cell in the details row of tablix in the parent report back to the parent report and including the extra parameters (Hidden) that the subreport requires.

On first running the report I get an error for the subreport **" One or more parameters were not specified for the subreport 'Report Name', located at: / Report Name'**, but that's fine as on first running the report I wanted the subreport hidden so expression in visibility of subreport for show / hide which is based on the parameters that are not passed on first running the report. So when first running the report you don't get the error as the subreport is not visible until the on click event.

When clicking on a row in the main tablix the report reloads as in action points back on itself and the parameters are passed for the subreport.